# Kafka Rack Aware Feature

Tags: apache-kafka

I have question about implementing **broker.rack** aware feature and rolling it back.

1. If I upgrade my existing cluster to support **rack aware** feature, will it impact any existing topics in terms of re-balancing the replicas?
2. If I rollback my upgrade to non rack-aware cluster, will there be any impact on existing topics?

For some reason, I could not able to start a microservice after the rollback, which reads messages from a non rack-aware topic.

Is there anything specific to know about, while implementing rack-aware feature?

Answer (score 1):

Enabling or disabling rack awareness does not impact existing topics, their assignment will stay the same.

Once rack awareness is enabled, new topic will be assigned replicas on as many racks as possible.

When enabling rack awaress, depending on the racks you set, you may want to reassign topics so they are all spread on as many racks as possible. If as said above it's not done automatically sp you have to do it yourself using the reassignment tools.